# Looking for a short story posted online, about a baby being grown in a artificial womb, but there's complications

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

Looking for an English short story posted online, about a baby being grown in a artificial womb, but there's complications.

Complications like marital strife between the couple that wanted the baby, such that the baby may or may not have been decanted at the end of the story.

I'm imagining the growth container / artificial womb / etc being man-portable, but that might just my imagination.

I do know that it does have a output method for status reports about the condition of the fetus inside, and that it seemed to bracket the sections about the fetus's parents.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From [Vice's Terraform](https://www.vice.com/en/topic/terraform), it's [Hysteria](https://www.vice.com/en/article/qv33zb/hysteria), summarized in a [companion piece](https://www.vice.com/en/article/d3dda7/what-to-expect-when-youre-expecting-a-baby-grown-in-an-artificial-womb) as:

> Elison slyly narrates this tale of cold feet, impulse decisions, and prenatal heists entirely through the gestation company's upbeat prompts and reminders. Through this lens, it becomes clear that one parent is falling more in love with the baby, while the other is falling into profound regret as the reality of parenthood sinks in.